# nullpointer exception on table.getSelectedRow()

Tags: java

I have a class A and a class B. 
In class A there is a constructor:

```
public  A() {
        getSelectedRow();
    }
```

This constructor calls:

```
public int getSelectedRow() {
    System.out.println("The row is : " + table.getSelectedRow());
    return table.getSelectedRow();

}
```

Up to here everything works fine!
The class B then calls the method `getSelectedRow()` like that:

```
        A results = new A();
        System.out.println("YEAH! IT'S: " + results.getSelectedRow());
```

I just want to find out the selected table row from class A. The problem is that I am getting a null pointer exception and i dont know why. if I dont call the method everything works fine.

CLASS A:

```
public class AllResultsFromDB extends JFrame {

    @SuppressWarnings("compatibility:9056676689615464658")
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 188850508334531506L;


    GUI ins = new GUI();
    JTable table;

    public AllResultsFromDB(GUI x) {
        final Vector columnNames = new Vector();
        final Vector data = new Vector();
        this.ins = x;


        try {


            /** Initializing GUI class
             * in order to call
             * getSelectedTable() method. **/

            Login sgui = new Login();


            String dburl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL";
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, sgui.getUsername(), sgui.getPassword());


            //  Fetch data from table specified by user

            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + ins.getSelectedTable() + " ORDER BY id";
            System.out.println(query);
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            ResultSetMetaData metad = rset.getMetaData();
            int columns = metad.getColumnCount();


            //  This loop gets the names of the columns

            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                columnNames.addElement(metad.getColumnName(i));
            }


            //  This loop gets the data inside the rows

            while (rset.next()) {
                final Vector row = new Vector(columns);


                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                    row.addElement(rset.getObject(i));

                }

                data.addElement(row);
            }

            rset.close();
            stmt.close();
            connection.close();


            //  Create table with results

            table = new JTable(data, columnNames) {

                    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {

                        return false;
                    }


                    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {

                        for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++) {
                            Object obj = getValueAt(row, column);
                            if (obj != null) {

                                return obj.getClass();

                            }
                        }

                        return Object.class;
                    }


                };


            JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
            getContentPane().add(scroll);


            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


            table.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                    //System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow());

                }

                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    //System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow());

                }

                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    //System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow());

                }

                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    //System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow());
                }

                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                    getSelectedRow();
                    if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {


                        //System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow());

                        Profile profile = new Profile();

                        try {

                            profile.getData();
                            //wait(500000);
                            profile.getImage();

                        } catch (Exception f) {
                        }
                        profile.setVisible(true);
                    }

                }
            });


        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }

    }

   public  AllResultsFromDB(int x) {
        x = getSelectedRow();
        System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow());
    }


    public int getSelectedRow() {
        System.out.println("The row is : " + table.getSelectedRow());
        return table.getSelectedRow();

    }

}
```

CLASS B:

```
public class Profile extends JFrame {


    AllResultsFromDB results = new AllResultsFromDB();

    public Profile(AllResultsFromDB x) {
        this.results=x;
        try {
            getData();
            getImage();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            jbInit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getImage() throws Exception {
        JLabel label;
        Image img;
        ImageIcon pic;
        JPanel panel;
        img = new ImageIcon("java.jpg").getImage();
        pic = new ImageIcon(img);
        label = new JLabel("", pic, JLabel.CENTER);
        panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 340, 310));
        panel.add(label, null);
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(new Dimension(1148, 336));
        this.getContentPane().add(panel, null);


    }

    public void getData() throws Exception {
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL";
        String username = "c##lambros";
        String password = "16111111";
        Connection conn = null;

        try {



            System.out.println("YEAH! IT'S: " + results.getSelectedRow());



            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

            String sql = "SELECT foto FROM criminals WHERE id = 5";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                //String name = resultSet.getString(1);
                //System.out.println("Name        = " + name);


                File image = new File("java.jpg");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(image);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

                //
                // Get the binary stream of our BLOB data
                //
                InputStream is = resultSet.getBinaryStream(1);
                while (is.read(buffer) > 0) {
                    fos.write(buffer);
                }

                fos.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
                conn.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void jbInit() throws Exception {
        this.setSize(new Dimension(816, 380));
        JLabel label;
        Image img;
        ImageIcon pic;
        JPanel panel;
        img = new ImageIcon("java.jpg").getImage();
        pic = new ImageIcon(img);
        label = new JLabel("", pic, JLabel.CENTER);
        panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 340, 310));
        panel.add(label, null);
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(new Dimension(1148, 336));
        this.getContentPane().add(panel, null);
    }



}
```

Comment: have you initialized `table`  ?

Comment: Yes i have. if i put a custom row it works fine. the problem starts when I am trying to "pull" the row number from class A to class B.

Comment: @JunedAhsan results is the instantiation of class A into class B

Comment: Where did you initialize the table? Please post a bit more code to be able to understand the context properly.

Comment: added the whole code to look at if its not a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the classB since you are creating a new instance

```
A results = new A();
```

The value present in the table.getSelectedRow() also gets created newly and will point to null.

So make sure that you do somthing

> A results = new A(selectedRow);

and in the constructor of the A,pass the argument to the function

```
    getSelectedRow(selectedRow);
```

Please note : Make sure that the value of the "table.selectedRow" is maintained

Answer (score 0):

If table is your instance variable in Class A then it might not be initialized when you are trying to access it in constructor of A.
And calling getSelectedRow from the constructor is not making any sense too.

Try to initialize the table variable in constructor instead of calling that method, it should work after it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the table object is not being initialized.
Try to initialize the table object in constructor....it is a good practice